# Does the consent process for the Revised Irish Protocol breach the Belfast Agreement?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, northern-ireland

The Belfast Agreement specifies that key decisions require cross-community support, and it specifies what this means.

In the Revised Irish Protocol, staying in the protocol arrangement requires a simple majority.

Surely this would need cross-community support that does not appear to be catered for in the protocol?

**References**

https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/840657/Declaration_by_Her_Majesty_s_Government_of_the_United_Kingdom_of_Great_Britain_and_Northern_Ireland_concerning_the_operation_of_the__Democratic_consent_in_Northern_Ireland__provision_of_the_Protocol_on_Ireland_Northern_Ireland.pdf

https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/136652/agreement.pdf

Comment: The following links explain why it doesn't http://www.democraticaudit.com/2019/10/29/matters-of-consent-the-withdrawal-agreement-does-not-violate-the-good-friday-agreement/   https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/europpblog/2019/01/11/breached-or-protected-the-principle-of-consent-in-northern-ireland-and-the-uk-governments-brexit-proposals/

Answer (score 2):

No. The relevant section of the Good Friday Agreement (Pages 7 and 8 in your linked copy) is Strand 1 (**DEMOCRATIC INSTITUTIONS IN NORTHERN IRELAND**) Section 5 (**SAFEGUARDS**):

> 5. There will be safeguards to ensure that all sections of the community can participate and work together successfully **in the operation of these institutions** and that all sections of the community are protected, including:
>
> *(a) to (c) skipped*
>
> (d) arrangements to ensure key decisions are taken on a cross-community basis;
>
> (i) either parallel consent, i.e. a majority of those members present and voting, including a majority of the unionist and nationalist designations present and voting;
>
> (ii) or a weighted majority (60%) of members present and voting, including at least 40% of each of the nationalist and unionist designations present and voting.

Emphasis mine.

In other words, the requirement within the GFA to ensure that key decisions have cross-community support pertains exclusively to the constitution of Northern Ireland; I.E. the existence, make-up, powers and functioning of the Assembly and the Northern Ireland Executive. It is not a principle that can be extrapolated to apply to whatever issue-of-the-day one side or other dislikes.